# C "#define" function name generation

Tags: c, c-preprocessor

I have `concrete_impl.h` (as is):

```
#ifdef TUPLE_ITERATOR_WITH_INDEX
    #define TUPLE_ITERATOR TUPLE_ITERATOR_NO_INDEX
    #define iterate_tuple_fname iterate_tuple_id
#else
    #define TUPLE_ITERATOR TUPLE_ITERATOR_INDEX
    #define iterate_tuple_fname iterate_tuple
#endif

#undef  iterate_tuple_fname_back
#define iterate_tuple_fname_back iterate_tuple_fname##_back

static void iterate_tuple_fname()         // ok 
{
}

static void iterate_tuple_fname_back()   // redefinition error
{
}
```

And `concrete.h` (as is):

```
#ifndef CONCRETE_H
#define CONCRETE_H

#define TUPLE_ITERATOR_WITH_INDEX
#include "concrete_impl.h"

#undef TUPLE_ITERATOR_WITH_INDEX
#include "concrete_impl.h"


#endif // CONCRETE_H
```

What I want to get - is 4 functions:

- iterate_tuple
- iterate_tuple_id
- iterate_tuple_back
- iterate_tuple_id_back

But on "_back" functions I have redefinition error. Why?

Comment: Playing with defines will make your code very messy, specially generating functions like this.
What's wrong with actually writing them?

Comment: @danikaze You mean writing them twice?

Comment: Yeah, I mean writing the actual functions you want to have defined. What's the point on calling twice to the same file to define functions in that way?
In the end you will have the same amount of code defined, and it's much more readable if all the functions are written and not defined with that kind of hacks

Comment: @danikaze functions not the same inside, they behavior are macro depended, also.

Comment: yeah I supposed that too :P and then when you write them you don't write them with the same inside lol. What I'm trying to say is sometimes we just obfuscate in making something automatically when it's better to use the manual way.

Comment: @danikaze This is not that case.

Comment: @danikaze it is the sacred duty of the programmer to always choose the automatic way if it's no more work than the manual way. *We do not serve the machine*.

Comment: @Leushenko I prefer writing readable and maintainable code instead of automatic one --depending on the case--

Comment: @Leushenko - Just make the code readable - even if it takes a little more effort. Then in the future you will not waste time figuring it out.

Comment: @EdHeal nope. Wrong. Laziness, impatience, hubris. Stick by *those* and you'll have no trouble in the future. Never write the same line twice or you're doing the machine's work for it, and there was no point in you ever becoming a programmer in the first place. Besides, well-metaprogrammed code is more maintainable and usually more readable anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`iterate_tuple_fname##_back` is nothing else than `iterate_tuple_fname_back`. To have `iterate_tuple_fname` replaced by its macro replacement list, you'll need a helper macro:

```
#define CONCAT(a, b) a ## b
#define iterate_tuple_fname_back CONCAT(iterate_tuple_fname, _back)
```

UPDATE: Sorry, have forgotten all about C after several years of C# programming.

It actually needs *double* run through helper macros:

```
#define CONCAT1(a, b) a ## b
#define CONCAT(a, b) CONCAT1(a, b)
#define iterate_tuple_fname_back CONCAT(iterate_tuple_fname, _back)
```

Comment: @tower120, then you'd better post the actual error message you're getting. You also might try running your code through the preprocessor (`gcc -E` or `cl.exe -E`).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently you misunderstand how the `##` operator works.

- If the preprocessing token adjacent to the `##` operator is a *parameter* of the current macro, then this parameter is recursively analyzed for further replacement *first*, and the result of that replacement substituted into the result.
- If the preprocessing token adjacent to the `##` operator is *not* a parameter of the current macro, then recursive analysis and replacement of that token does not take place. The token is simply concatenated with the other token.

Later, once all parameters are substituted and all concatenations are joined, the entire result is rescanned again for further replacements. But then it is already be too late for your example.

In your case you defined this macro

```
#define iterate_tuple_fname_back iterate_tuple_fname##_back
```

Since `iterate_tuple_fname` is not a parameter of this macro, no early replacement occurs for `iterate_tuple_fname`. The whole thing is immediately concatenated into `iterate_tuple_fname_back` and only after that it is rescanned. But rescan finds nothing to replace there, so `iterate_tuple_fname_back` is the final result.

If you want the preprocessor to replace the left-hand side of the `##` operator (which was your intent apparently), you absolutely have to use a macro parameter on the left-hand side, as in

```
#define ITF_back(prefix) prefix##_back
```

and then you can use this macro as

```
ITF_back(iterate_tuple_fname)
```

Now the rescan and recursive replacement inside `iterate_tuple_fname` will occur early, before the concatenation with the `_back` part. I.e. it will work as you wanted it to.